# Filtar un array con valores desde otro array array?

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo este problema, tengo este array:

```
let datos = [
  'Australia',
  'Canada',
  'China',
  'Denmark',
  'France',
  'Netherlands',
  'United Kingdom',
];
```

Y necesito excluir todo los paises que esta en este  array

```
let datosFiltrar = ['Australia', 'Canada', 'Netherlands', 'United Kingdom'];
```

para obetener el siguiente outpot:

```
[ 'China', 'Denmark', 'France', 'United Kingdom' ]
```

Lo he logrado solucionar de esta manera:

```js
/* eslint-disable */
let datos = [
  'Australia',
  'Canada',
  'China',
  'Denmark',
  'France',
  'Netherlands',
  'United Kingdom',
];

let datosFiltrar = ['Australia', 'Canada', 'Netherlands', 'United Kingdom'];

console.log(datos.filter((val) => val !== 'Australia' && val !== 'Canada' && val !== 'Netherlands' && val !== 'Kingdom'  ));
```

Pero considero que no es la mejor solucion, Gracias..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes filtrar el array de una forma mas simple y es:

```
let datos = [
    'Australia',
    'Canada',
    'China',
    'Denmark',
    'France',
    'Netherlands',
    'United Kingdom',
];
let datosFiltrar = ['Australia', 'Canada', 'Netherlands', 'United Kingdom'];
let res = datos.filter(pais => !datosFiltrar.includes(pais));
console.log(res);
```